# Should I store the local time for events instead of UTC?

Tags: time, jodatime

I am currently storing events of some entities in UTC time but I am not sure if I should do that in this case. Imagine there's an event at 10pm local time (-4h UTC) and a mobile App fetches "*todays events*". This could e.g. look like this:

1. App sends request to fetch all clubs in the near location
2. After receiving all clubs it sends a request to get all events for today. It therefore sends the local time Sun. 10pm to the server.
3. The server would convert the local time of the mobile device to UTC Mon. 1am and fetch all events from Monday. But of course that was not what I wanted.

Fetching all events from the clubs and convert them to their local time using their local time offset information is not really a great solution.

So wouldn't it be better to just store all events in local time? In that case the mobile App would send its local time to the server which would be able to query all events from the clubs in local time as well.

This sounds much simpler to me but I am not sure if I overlook something.

So what would I do in this case?

Comment: This has been discussed many times on StackOverflow. Please search, especially for "java date best practice".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing everything in UTC is probably the best solution.

You don't say how you are "storing" the dates/times, but if you are using Dates or Joda equivalents, then you should know that their underlying representation is effectively in UTC (they represent a moment in time as an offset in milliseconds since the "Epoch", which is Midnight, Jan 1, 1970 UTC). These dates only have a timezone when you format them as Strings.

Most databases do something similar (store the date in a common timezone, usually UTC). The major exception that I've found is the generally available date-time related column types in MS SqlServer which by default store everything in the local timezone of the server.

Also be aware that if you use SQLite, and you store a date/time by passing a String in SQL that contains a timezone, SQLite will store it without warning, but will ignore the timezone and assume that the timezone is UTC, giving you a result other than what you might expect.

For more on this, see my (old) blog post at http://greybeardedgeek.net/2012/11/24/java-dates/

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct. Some more thoughts here.

A time zone is more than the offset from UTC mentioned in the Question. A time zone is also the set of past, present, and future rules for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time. You should refer to a time zone by its [proper name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), continent plus Slash plus city or region. Never use the 3-4 letter codes such as EST or IST.

To search for events in the user's "today", **you must know the user’s time zone**. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal. After the stroke of midnight in Paris we still have a few hours of “yesterday” left to go in Montréal.

While you can make a guess as to the user’s time zone, the most reliable way is to ask the user.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTimeZone now = DateTimeZone.now( zone );
DateTime today = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
// Search for events that start >= today AND that start < tomorrow.
```

To search Joda-Time objects, use the Comparator built into `DateTime`. That comparator works across objects of various time zones.

To query a database, convert that pair of `DateTime` objects into [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) objects. You do that by [extracting](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis()) and passing the count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970 in UTC.

```
long m = today.getMillis();
java.sql.Timestamp tsToday = new java.sql.Timestamp( m );
```

Comment: What use do I have here knowing the users time zone? I can't search events using his local time since all dates are stored in UTC. At the moment I am converting the local client time to UTC and send it as a ISO8061 GMT String to the server. But this would give me the wrong day in some cases like I'm mentioning in my question. I'm somehow not getting it ..

Comment: Virtually all databases have date/time functions that convert and consider time zones. You can use these functions to properly search for an item containing a date in a range specified in a particular timezone, even with the data stored "in utc". As I mentioned,  dates only actually have timezones when you format them. If youtell us what database you're using, we can probably come up with an example for you.

Comment: @StefanFalk **If you want to search using the user’s definition of today, *you need to know her time zone.*** Once you have a time zone in hand you can determine when the day begins for her and when tomorrow begins. That is the code I gave you in this Answer. For a database query that pair is converted to UTC. For object comparison in memory, no conversion is needed as Joda-Time’s methods `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` works with DateTime values of various time zones. Again, you need to spend some time reading other postings on StackOverflow to wrap your head around date-time work.